# How to expose cache statistics for Guava Cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, prometheus, micrometer

I'm using spring boot 1.5 and I cannot expose guava cache statistics in `/prometheus` endpoint. Eventually I can expose it as JMX but then I dont know how to wire these things up. Is there some easier way how to do it?

I am creating the cache with cache builder as following:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        final GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
        final CacheBuilder<Object, Object> cacheBuilder = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(5000)
                .recordStats()
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        cacheManager.setCacheBuilder(cacheBuilder);
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(Lists.newArrayList("TEST_CACHE"));
        return cacheManager;
    }
```

I am using `.recordStats()` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the Guava chache metrics by using the [GuavaCacheMetrics binder](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/cache/GuavaCacheMetrics.java)

```
GuavaCacheBuilder.monitor(meterRegistry, aCache, "myCacheName")
```

Notice since you are using a cache builder with the `CacheManager` you would need to make that `monitor` call for each individual cache.

There are other ways to approach this, and the `CacheManager` is automatically instrumented in SpringBot 2.x I believe. So upgrading will give you a simpler integration.

Comment: Thing is, it does need a cache which is extended from com.google.common.cache.Cache, but the cache class got from CacheManager is GuavaCache from org.springframework package. So I am not able to use this method.

Comment: Thanks, just want to mention that it works in conjunction with `recordStats()` method in `CacheBuilder`, otherwise all metrics will be reported as zeros.